# Transitions: How to change parent view size after transition is finished?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

In my app, I have a linear layout of views. The size of these views may change due to the changes in their own layout. In particular, the first view (`sceneRoot`) is comprised of a hideable part (`view1`) and an always visible part (`view2`). I want to animate the appearing and disappearing of `view1` in two steps:

- if `view1` **disappears**, 1) `view1` fades out and then 2) `view2` moves up ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqevq.gif)),
- if `view1` **appears**, 1) `view2` moves down and then 2) `view1` fades in ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rVGP.gif)).

This is the result so far:

[image: disappear transition]
[image: appear transition]

The problem is that `sceneRoot` changes its bounds immediately as soon as `view1` changes visibility. `view3` jumps to its new position, making the disappear transition look cut.

Ideally, I would like the height of `sceneRoot` to animate accordingly. If this is not attainable, I would like the height to change *after* the disappear transition is done, not before it starts.

Here's the layout in question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scene_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="View 1 (Hideable)"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="View 2"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View 3"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this simplified example a single `LinearLayout` would suffice. In real-life scenario, though, layout flattening is not so easily achievable.

Here's how I change `view1`'s visibility:

```
private fun toggleView1Visibility() {
    TransitionManager.endTransitions(sceneRoot)

    val isView1Appearing = view1.visibility != View.VISIBLE

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(
        sceneRoot,
        createTransition(isView1Appearing)
    )

    view1.visibility = if (isView1Appearing) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}

private fun createTransition(
    isView1Appearing: Boolean
): Transition {
    val view1Fade = Fade().apply {
        addTarget(view1)
        duration = 750
    }

    val view2ChangeBounds = ChangeBounds().apply {
        addTarget(view2)
        duration = 750
    }

    return TransitionSet().apply {
        ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL

        if (isView1Appearing) {
            addTransition(view2ChangeBounds)
            addTransition(view1Fade)
        } else {
            addTransition(view1Fade)
            addTransition(view2ChangeBounds)
        }
    }
}
```

What options do I have to fix disappear transition without resorting to layout flattening?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in parent LL.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. Probably because parent LL doesn't know anything about changes in its children. It will only react to changes in visibility of the entire `sceneRoot`.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, transition targets do not have be direct children of the scene root.

Adding more targets to `ChangeBounds()` did the trick:

```
private fun createTransition(
        isView1Appearing: Boolean
): Transition {
    val view1Fade = Fade().apply {
        addTarget(view1)
        duration = 750
    }

    val changeBounds = ChangeBounds().apply {
        addTarget(sceneRoot)

        addTarget(view2)
        addTarget(view3)

        duration = 750
    }

    return TransitionSet().apply {
        ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL

        if (isView1Appearing) {
            addTransition(changeBounds)
            addTransition(view1Fade)
        } else {
            addTransition(view1Fade)
            addTransition(changeBounds)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Great if u found the Answer. Here i am also adding an Answer although its in Java, cause i dont known much about kotlin.

```
 private void toggleView1Visibility() {

        final int originalDimension = sceneRoot.getHeight();
        final int newDimension =sceneRoot.getHeight();


        Boolean isView1Appearing = view1.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE;

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, new TransitionSet()
                .addTransition(new ChangeBounds()));
        if (isView1Appearing){
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = sceneRoot.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = newDimension;
            sceneRoot.setLayoutParams(params);
            view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE );
        }

        else {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, new TransitionSet()
                    .addTransition(new ChangeBounds()));

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = sceneRoot.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = originalDimension;
            sceneRoot.setLayoutParams(params);
            view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Remember here sceneroot is the parent LL of the layout.